# Client router cannot connect to different AP with same name

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

In my shop I need to provide Internet access to my cash register. I connected the register via Ethernet cable to a TP-Link TL-WR802N router in client mode. As access point I use my Android mobile phone as wifi hotspot. I configured the router to use the phone AP and it works fine.

Sometimes however my partner replaces me in the shop, so I configured her phone as a second hotspot, with same SSID, encryption and password. The phone is also Android. Unfortunately the router refuses to connect.

I can reconfigure the router to connect to this second phone, but then it refuses to connect to mine. Since the two APs share the same configuration, I thought it would switch from one to the other without problems, as I have read in other posts.

Please note the two mobile hotspots are never active at the same time. I tried changing channels, but that didn't help. It seems that the router is tied to a specific MAC address.

Is there some setting to be changed in the router? How can I make it connect to more than one hotspot?

Comment: The TP-Link remembers the BSSID (the ID of the specific access-point that it is connecting to). If you can find an option anywhere in the TP-Link router to ignore the BSSID - then you are good to go (as it will simply connect to the same Wireless AP). Note: This is actually a security issue. The TP-Link is doing the right thing by NOT trying to connect and sending pass-phrase to the same Wireless AP as that would be a security issue. Imagine an attacker copying your wireless AP name - they will get your passphrase as the client will send in the passphrase to the attacker.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The configuration options in client mode are pretty basic. In the form where I can enter the hotspot settings, I can only see a tick box 'Lock to AP', which is unticked by default. I'll check further, but maybe there is no option to ignore the BSSID.